# what's meaning of `find \( -perm -04000 -o -perm -02000 \)`

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, find, bit

I know this:

```
find . -perm -664

       Search  for  files which have read and write permission for their owner and group, 
and which other users can read.
```

but I can't figure out what is meaning of `04000` and `02000`, maybe the `lsattr` could tell me? but I also have no idea about that.

THX.

Comment: `man 2 chmod` has the definitions

Comment: Reading the manual page of the command you are using is always a good idea. An other good idea is never to run a command you are unsure what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the conclusion that both commands below give the same output:

SUID permission search command:

- `find / -perm -u=s -type f -ls 2>/dev/null`
- `find / -perm -04000 -type f -ls 2>/dev/null`

and also:

SGID permission search command:

- `find / -perm -g=s -type f -ls 2>/dev/null`
- `find / -perm -02000 -type f -ls 2>/dev/null`

Therefore `find \( -perm -04000 -o -perm -02000 \)` is searching for the permission bits of SUID and SGID. Documentation here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-Bits.html